# Reduce gap between left-view and curser in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I am using below code for adding left view in textfield:

```
func setUI()
{
    txtUserCode.leftViewMode = .always
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 7, y: 0, width: 18, height: txtUserCode.frame.size.height))
    label.text = "@"
    txtUserCode.leftView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 18, height: txtUserCode.frame.size.height)
    txtUserCode.leftView = label
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    txtUserCode.leftView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

But the problem is there is gap between left view and curser you can see in screen shot.

[image]

**See there is small gap between curser and the left view, you can see between 'premB' and '@'**

Any help or suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: What about doing `label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5` (or something else), so the font size adapt to itself?

Comment: You edited your question, so it seems because the end of the red and the start of the first letter is too wide. If that's the case, then you need to subclass the `UITextField` and override some of its methods like `textRect(forBounds:)`.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to below.

```
func setUI()
{
    txtUserCode.leftViewMode = .always
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 7, y: 0, width: 18, height: txtUserCode.frame.size.height))
    label.text = "@"
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 7, y: 0, width: label.frame.size.width, height: txtUserCode.frame.size.height)
    txtUserCode.leftView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: label.frame.size.width, height: txtUserCode.frame.size.height)
    txtUserCode.leftView = label
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    txtUserCode.leftView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

To get the exact size, first make sizeToFit for the label & instead of 18, give the width of the label.

Add below line and try again.

```
txtUserCode.borderStyle = .none
```

Comment: @guru : try `width: label.frame.size.width+3`

Comment: Its not related to label its related to leftView, there is small gap between curser and the left view. but any how i am not able to reduce the space.

Comment: I think my last image was confusing you, i have updated the question.

Comment: @guru : can you try `txtUserCode.borderStyle = .none` and let me know

Comment: But what about when i need border.

Comment: @guru : `txtUserCode.borderWidth=2 txtUserCode.borderColor=.green`

Comment: will check this one.

Comment: problem is solved :) but not found the cause of this, this is strange behaviour.if there is any other way to do it will be better, because i am using default textfield :(

Comment: @guru : cause is because you selected textfield with borderStyle which default gives some padding...

Comment: sorry, but i can not set borderStyle = .none because i have more textfield in the same view, and if, i set border from my own it will not look like default.So the solution is not universally accepted.

Comment: I think @Larme's comment is better solution.